# WPF color effect for UI element

Tags: wpf, binding, grid, opacity, effect

How do I add a color effect to a UI element?

For example, it should look more yellow, so pixels have a more yellow color.
All I need is to make my black form a bit white, while it is inactive.

Comment: Interesting question.  Do you want to enhance the yellow pixels of the existing colour?  Or replace the existing colour with a brighter hue of yellow?  Both of these are triggerable.

Comment: To make it look a bit white, you could set the `Opacity` a bit lower while it is over a white background.

Comment: @GarryVass i want to enhance the yellow pixels of the existing colour , existing color are close to black color.

Comment: @FlorianGl looks good solution for image in yellow backgroud form. I need this effect for form which background is an image, and other controls of course.

Comment: @GarryVass , i want make white semi transparent layer on window.

Comment: I am starting to understand now.  I think.  Do you want to place a veneer of almost transparency over the entire client area?  And to turn this veneer on and off?

Comment: Thanks you for response @GarryVass, Yes yes! I want to place a veneer over the inactive window (when MessageBos.ShowDialod() called in code ) . The veneer must be semi transparent that user can see windows inside color veneer. Yes and  turn veneer on and off (off when it is active).

Comment: got it, I'll put an answer in for you in a moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your clarifications, the effect you want to achieve is to place a translucent veneer over the client area, and adjust its appearance programmatically.  The technique for this is to use the WPF Grid.  This control allows for layering.  Here's a Xaml fragment that sets up two layers...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" x:Key="MyVeneerBrush"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource MyVeneerBrush}" Opacity="{Binding VeneerOpacity}"/>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <!--Layout goes here-->
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" FontSize="52"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The first layer contains the veneer and the second layer contains the content.  Opacity on the first layer can be set from 0 (totally transparent) to 1 (totally visible), and in between values will give a translucent quality.  You would need to write your ViewModel along these lines...

```
public class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        TurnVeneerOn();
    }
    private void TurnVeneerOff()
    {
        VeneerOpacity = 0;
    }
    private void TurnVeneerOn()
    {
        VeneerOpacity = 0.4;
    }
    private double _veneerOpacity;
    public double VeneerOpacity
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _veneerOpacity; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _veneerOpacity)
            {
                _veneerOpacity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("VeneerOpacity");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This VM exposes a property that binds to the View and controls the opacity of they first layer in the Xaml.  There's two indicative methods thrown in to help get you started.

You will need to experiment with the window background and the brush and various levels of opacity to get the *exact* effect you are after, but there's enough here to get how it works.

The key is to use the Grid's layering capability.

Comment: Thank you , but it works fine if second grid have not Background. Else  shows only second grid's background. In my case windows starts with grid and grid has background image.

Comment: You didn't mention that part.  You would need to add the complementary opacity to the second grid also.  It is the same technique.

Comment: I set opacity on second grid , and changed it . Thank you for  Grid's layering capability technique!

Comment: All part of the service :)  Be real sure to copy Keftmedei's extension method into your library too!

Answer (score 3):

I recently needed a gradient effect that would go from a specified color to a lighter version of that color. I came across this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/26a68ffd-bd51-4a72-8eda-d1dcff556f1d/make-color-lighter) which works very nicely.

Here is the code as an extension method

```
public static Color Interpolate(this Color color1, Color color2, float percentage)
    {
        double a1 = color1.A / 255.0, r1 = color1.R / 255.0, g1 = color1.G / 255.0, b1 = color1.B / 255.0;
        double a2 = color2.A / 255.0, r2 = color2.R / 255.0, g2 = color2.G / 255.0, b2 = color2.B / 255.0;
        byte a3 = Convert.ToByte((a1 + (a2 - a1) * percentage) * 255);
        byte r3 = Convert.ToByte((r1 + (r2 - r1) * percentage) * 255);
        byte g3 = Convert.ToByte((g1 + (g2 - g1) * percentage) * 255);
        byte b3 = Convert.ToByte((b1 + (b2 - b1) * percentage) * 255);
        return Color.FromArgb(a3, r3, g3, b3);
    }
```

In my case I mix in 50 % white

```
BackgroundColor.Interpolate(Colors.White, .5f);
```

Comment: ok, and how to use this for all window , there are many colors on it.

Comment: You said all you want to do is make your black form a bit white. If that is not the case, I would look in to other solutions like drawing a control on top and set a lower opacity.

Comment: No , blck color but not all pixels black , most of it- black but exists othe colors too

Answer (score 1):

For enhancing your yellow pixels, you could blend in a colored layer Photoshop style. For Photoshop style blend modes, you could use [Cory Plotts' library](http://www.cplotts.com/2009/11/06/blend-modes-now-opacity-aware/) and experiment with different blend modes. However, this may be a bit overkill for what you want to do; in which case you should try the following:

If you want your element to have a simple faded look, simply add a semi-transparent layer on top of your element as `keftmedei` suggested. Here's an example:

```
<yourElement Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="50" />
```

This would change to:

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="50">
    <yourElement />
    <Rectangle Fill="#60FFFFFF" />
</Grid>
```

Change the opacity level by changing the `60` in `Fill="#60FFFFFF"`

Comment: And what if  <yourElement /> has background ?

Comment: I mixed up the order. The `Rectangle` acting as your opacity mask should be on top of your content. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I'm happy to be of help